# How do I implement Office 365 Authentication in ASP.NET Core and Blazor (Server-Client app)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, office365

I have downloaded and installed "ASP.NET Core and Blazor updates in .NET Core 3.0 Preview 9".

I wanted to implement Office 365 Authentication in ASP.NET Core and Blazor (Server-Client app).

I have used two layout pages for login and admin panel. When user start the application then it reaches the login page (login.razor and its layout is LandingLayout). Once user successful office 365 logged in then it redirects to admin dashboard page (dashboard.razor and its layout is MainLayout).

- I need to show/hide menus based on user groups (from office 365 after
  successful login)
- How do I bind user information in Claim authentication
- How do I get user roles or groups from Office 365
- How do I get list of user emails from Office 365 with same domain
  logged in by admin user. This list of emails will bind in
  dropdownlist - select)
- How do I setup startup Razor Page instead of using index.html (in
  wwwroot Client app)

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/get-started-with-office-365-management-apis