# Blazor (Server-Side) with Organizational/Office 365/Microsoft Account Authentication; How to do Local Multiple Roles?

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, office365, blazor

There's a somewhat similar question here that was asked 8 months ago with no response:
[How do I implement Office 365 Authentication in ASP.NET Core and Blazor (Server-Client app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942802/how-do-i-implement-office-365-authentication-in-asp-net-core-and-blazor-server)

**What I do have is a new project in Visual Studio Community 2019:**

1. Type is Blazor Server-Side app.
2. I selected "Work or School" for authentication when creating the project. To use Microsoft Accounts.
3. I selected organizational "Single Tenant" account type. Filled in my org's domain.
4. I went to my Azure Portal and the app appeared there. The Tenant/Client ID match the ones in appsettings.json.
5. When I launch the app it asks for my organizational login and it redirects to the homepage fine!

*The issue is all users have the same levels of access.*

**What I want to create is a page (visible to an Admin) where I can:**

1. add organizational users by searching the active directory.
2. assign roles (stored in my local database).

**My question is:**

- How can I assign roles to o365 users from within my app? The scope is my app only so to be stored in a local db.
- If the above is not doable, what is the alternative to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could probably store all the users in the local db, if you were developing a multi tenant app or an app that would be used by other companies and such, then I may go that route in terms local db and etc. 
if it just for your org, and you have access to aad, I would create roles in the app reg manifest, then assign them in the enterprise application. here's how: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

then in blazor at least for .netcore, i would access them with something like this

You can only see this if you're an admin or superuser.

or the authorize attribute.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#role-based-and-policy-based-authorization

Hope that helps you get started,

**Update**

As per your update, you wanted to know if you could do it without admin access. Once you have the user authenticated from aad, you could add some code to query a database, for the username, and add role or other claims to the claimsprincipal, as per https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/11/01/authorization-claims.aspx

Comment: Many thanks, this is a valid workaround. I have just tried it and it works! I'll wait a few days to see if there's a solution without admin access to AAD.

Comment: sure there is, if you wanted to, once you have the user authenticated from aad, you could add some code to query a database, for the username, and add role or other claims to the claimsprincipal, https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/11/01/authorization-claims.aspx

Comment: Please add this as the official answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Just added, Thanks